# Transfer Skyrim saves from Xbox 360 Harddrive to PC

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

My xbox 360 was fried in a lightening storm, we've checked the Harddrive, and everything is still on there. But I'm wondering how I can get my PC saves straight off the harddrive using a SATA adapter to hook the harddrive to my computer. I just dont know how to access my Skyrim saves straight from the harddrive.

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's possible. I found something on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mfgrp/psa_you_can_transfer_skyrim_savegame_files_from/). You need a program called [Modio](http://www.game-tuts.com/community/modio.php), which can read Xbox360 formated drives.
It says that you need to copy the data to USB, but I think that it should work with a SATA to usb adapter.

> Copy the save to your 360 Formatted USB Drive. Open with Modio. Click open from device locate the save file and open it. Click the file contents tab. Extract savegame.dat rename to savegame.ess and put it into your Skyrim save game location.